npm UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
Yesterday I cloned a Github repository to my Webstorm (I have a Student Pack license). Then, I clicked the button " Run 'npm install' ". After that, this error appeared:
UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
The node modules directory for Angular project didn't install.
At that moment, I had Angular CLI 17.0.9, and the Angular project I wanted to clone was created on Angular CLI 17.3.5.
The first thing I did was uninstall my Angular CLI, it was installed globally on my computer 2 months ago. I executed these commands:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
After that, I saw that some people on StackOverflow executed npm cache clean --force, so I did the same.
Then, I tried: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest but this error appeared:
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-20T15_45_09_572Z-debug-0.log
This is the information of that log.
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.5.0
2 info using node@v20.12.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 6ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Home.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 15ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
17 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm install @angular/cli@latest
21 verbose argv "install" "--global" "@angular/cli@latest"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-20T15_45_09_572Z-
25 verbose logfile C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-20T15_45_09_572Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 14ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 63ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 timing idealTree:init Completed in 16ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree Completed in 71923ms
36 timing command:install Completed in 71958ms
37 verbose type system
38 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
38 verbose stack     at ClientRequest. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
38 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
38 verbose stack     at _destroy (node:_http_client:880:13)
38 verbose stack     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:900:5)
38 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
39 verbose cwd C:\Users\Home
40 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
41 verbose node v20.12.2
42 verbose npm  v10.5.0
43 error code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
44 error errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
45 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
46 verbose exit 1
47 timing npm Completed in 72630ms
48 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1713627910235
49 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1713627910255
50 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:userRequests 1713627910273
51 verbose code 1
52 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-20T15_45_09_572Z-debug-0.log
I really need to work on my university project and now I can't even install Angular with npm. I need help as soon as posible.
I saw videos on Youtube about this problem, they said that it is a problem about SSL Cetificates, Firewall or Proxy. The only thing I did was to execute the next command:
npm ping
And this appeared:
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-20T15_45_09_572Z-debug-0.log
